# Установка MySQL на Python (Windows)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Стоит Python 3.7.0.
Нужно установить MySQL для Python.
Как это правильно сделать?
Ввожу команду `pip install mysql` и вот что выдаёт:

> ```
> Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe 
> -u -c "import setuptools, 
> tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
> ujjny6b3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
> (__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
>  __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
> record-y4292w3s\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
> compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
> install-ujjny6b3\mysqlclient\
> ```

Comment: Я что-то не понял, вы хотите установить СУБД на python? Или есть такая библиотека?

Comment: Возможно, я что-то делаю неправильно, я ещё совсем зелёный. Мне нужно просто работать с MySQL через Python, вот. :)

Comment: используйте библиотеку, например, mysqldb

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqldb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysqldb

Comment: Тогда mysqlclient

Comment: mysqlclient выдаёт ту же ошибку, что и в первом случае, когда я писал просто mysql

Comment: Поставил mysql-connector-python, всё установилось, но я не понимаю в чём разница. Можете пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: Разные библиотеки, разные методы